# Find the mistake in following proof

Tags: limits, proof-verification

With condition $x\neq c$

$\neg(\underbrace{0<x-c}_{p}) \Leftrightarrow \underbrace{0<c-x}_{\neg p}$

$ 1.(\underbrace{0<x-c}_{p} \vee \underbrace{0<c-x}_{\neg p})\wedge (\underbrace{\delta >x-c}_{q} \wedge \underbrace{\delta>c-x}_{r}))$

by distribution of conjunction over disjunction we have
$\Leftrightarrow(0<x-c\wedge\delta>x-c\wedge\delta>c-x)\vee(0<c-x\wedge\delta>x-c\wedge\delta>c-x)$
$\Leftrightarrow (c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge c<x)\vee(c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge x<c)$

$\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge x\neq c}_{s}$

$ 2.(\underbrace{0<x-c}_{p}\wedge \underbrace{\delta >x-c}_{q})\vee(\underbrace{\delta>c-x}_{r}\wedge\underbrace{0<c-x}_{\neg p})$

$\Leftrightarrow (0<x-c<\delta)\vee (0<c-x<\delta)$
$\Leftrightarrow (-\delta<x-c<\delta \wedge 0<x-c)\vee(-\delta<c-x<\delta \wedge 0<c-x)$
$\Leftrightarrow (c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge c<x)\vee(c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge x<c)$

$\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{c-\delta<x<c+\delta \wedge x\neq c}_{s}$

Since $(p \vee \neg p)\wedge(q\wedge r)\not \Leftrightarrow (p\wedge q)\vee(r \wedge \neg p)$

Have $s \not \Leftrightarrow s$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I found this when i was doing some proof for limits, and i have no idea where is the mistake :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using propositional variables $p$, $q$, and $r$. As propositional variables, they have nothing logically to do with each other, and hence it is indeed true that $(p \lor \neg p) \land (q\land r)$ is not logically equivalent to $(p \land q) \lor (r \land \neg p)$

However, in your derivation you gave $p$, $q$, and $r$ a specific meaning and, moreover, a meaning that allowed you to combine some of the information contained therein. That is, you appealed to the internal structure of the statements, rather than purely $p$'s, $q$'s, and $r$'s. This meant that you seemed to monstrate a lgical equivalence that really wasn't.

Indeed, you were using all kinds of mathematical assumptions regarding the nature of numbers, and the use of addition, smaller than, etc. As such, all you really showed were certain *mathematical* equivalences, rather than *logical* ones.

Consider a simpler example:

$p$ is the claim $a<b$

$q$ is the claim $b>a$

Well, obviously we have $a<b \Leftrightarrow b>a$ ... and yet it is not a logical truth that $p \Leftrightarrow q$

Comment: Thanks for your responding. I would like to know how can I avoid that kind of mistake in proof, futher more how to write this correctly(maybe how to choose  propositional variables correctly to make them equivalent, if this is the mistake), and please let me know if there is any articles or books about this.

In your example, p,q are the same, so we only consider the case TT,FF in truth table that are both true for  p⇔q, therefore  p⇔q hold. Or we can just denote them with same propositional variable to avoid this kind of confusion. But i didn't see anything like this in my proof.

Comment: @subcat yes, my example is pretty obvious, but in your case something similar is going on that prevents certain truth-value combinations ... it's just a lot more hidden.

Comment: I think you are right, the two false cases can never happen, take them out, they are indeed equivalent.